# on IOS grid-template-rows does nor work correctly with "1fr"

Tags: css, css-grid

I am facing a strange problem on IOS (chrome, safari):

```
.pageContainer {
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 100px;
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "main"
            "footer"
}
```

It works fine on PC (chrome, android), on Android, On MacOS (Including Safari) BUT on IOS, 
grid-template-rows: **100px 1fr 100px** just create trouble: 
Looks like IOS is unable to handle correctly 1fr and takes the WHOLE screen and not the available space.

On IOS, I must use a fixed value that gives the correct value 
like 100px 500px 100px

```
header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: static;
}

article {
    grid-area: main;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    grid-area: footer;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: static;
}
```

My layout has a static header and footer and the article can be scrolled.

Comment: Maybe instead of `1fr` try `calc(100vh - 200px)`.

Comment: Or try `height: 100vh` on `.pageContainer` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved that with **minmax**

```
grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(200px,1fr) 100px;
```

Comment: Thanks it really work. it still the best solution?

Comment: Appears to still be the case in 2023!